# How to allow .config, .map, .browser files to be downloaded IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

ITo download updates for a game, I've configured IIS 7.5 to download any type of file such as .html, .xml, .aspx etc. But there is one problem.

I am not able to download the files of type .map, .browser, .config. Actually these are files related to game. Without these files the update doesn't complete.

Can you please help me in solving these issues.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add MIME types for these extensions.

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".config" mimeType="text/xml" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".map" mimeType="text/plain" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".browser" mimeType="text/plain" />
      </staticContent>
   </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

On side note making these file available to client may cause serious security threat.